# Method To Delete 2nd Label, Then First Label, Not Functioning Correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I know I am missing something obvious, but I just cannot see it. This method is meant to compare the text of a label to the text of a text box, and then delete the text. So if the 1st label reads "Puppy" and the 2nd label reads "Kittens," and the text box says "Kittens," the method should delete the text of the 2nd label and leave the 1st label's text. If the 2nd label is blank, then the method should delete the text of the 1st label.

But no matter how I mess with the method, either it deletes the 2nd label but not the 1st, deletes both of them, or deletes neither of them. Here's what I've tried
(lblFabric1 is the 1st label, lblFabric2 is the 2nd label, txtType is the text box):

```
-(IBAction)btnDelete:(id)sender
{
  if ((self.lblFabric2.text== self.txtType.text))
   {
     self.lblFabric2.text = @"";
   }
  else if ((self.lblFabric2.text != self.txtType.text))
   {
     self.lblFabric1.text=@"";
   }
}
```

It deletes the 2nd label, but not the 1st label. If I try to set the "Else if" to:

```
else if ((self.lblFabric2.text==@""))
```

it gives me an error (""Direct comparison of a string literal has undefined behavior.") Am I just going about this the wrong way? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use == or != for string comparison in Objective C. You need to use the `isEqualToString` or `isEqual` method.

```
if (([self.lblFabric2.text isEqualToString:self.txtType.text]))
```

When you use == or != you are comparing the pointers where the strings are stored.

Comment: Oh my gosh I could kiss you. This was exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

To compare `NSString`s use:

```
if ([myString1 isEqualToString:myString2])
```

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/isEqualToString%3a)

Answer (score 0):

Compairing String literals using == is not guaranteed to behave as you might expect. Use `isEqual:` or `isEqualToString:` instead.

See http://nshipster.com/equality/.

Answer (score 0):

When you are comparing `NSString`s with `==` what you are actually comparing are two memory addresses and that is not what you are really intended for. You want to compare the values of two strings what `==` operator is not suitable for and thus you are getting the warning

> Direct comparison of a string literal has undefined behavior.

To compare the values of `NSString`s you should use `isEqualToString:` method. You could have also use `isEqual:` method derived from `NSObject` class but that is not suitable for Unicode comparison. So `isEqualToString:` is always the safest bet.

After using `isEqualToString:` your code should look something like:

```
-(IBAction)btnDelete:(id)sender
{
  if ([self.lblFabric2.text isEqualToString:self.txtType.text])
   {
     self.lblFabric2.text = @"";
   }
  else
   {
     self.lblFabric1.text=@"";
   }
}
```